# Return users mapped drive letter from network drive remote

Tags: batch-file, cmd, net-use

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the users mapped drive letter from a network drive. I've read a few posts here but they all seem to be around mapping/unmapping drives, whereas I simply need to know what drive the user has that network drive mapped to.

From a command prompt I use:
    Net Use s:
for example will give me the name of the networked drive (\servershare\file\sharename\shared), however

```
Net Use \\servershare\file\sharename\shared
```

just gives "The command completed successfully", where I need 'S:' returning.

How do I get the drive letter returned for a specific network drive?

Comment: Read `net use /help`:  When used `NET USE` without options, it lists the computer's connections.

Comment: net use | findstr /r "^.*[A-Z]:" | findstr "personnel" - this works and gives the the drive letter for the specific drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch file like this will work:

```
@FOR /F "tokens=2" %%D IN ('net use ^| find ":" ^| find /I "\\SERVER\SHARE"') DO @ECHO Drive letter is %%D
```

Notes:

- Replace `ECHO Drive letter is %%D` with whatever code you want now that the drive letter is known, possibly a multi-line code block surrounded by `(` and `)`. Replace `\\SERVER\SHARE` with the share you're looking for.
- If there's no drive mapped to the share, the statement after `DO` will never execute. If there's more than one drive mapped to the share, it will execute once for each drive.
- You could skip the first `^| find ":"` pipe if you're sure there won't be any connections without a drive letter (e.g. created with `net use \\SERVER\SHARE` as opposed to `net use S: \\SERVER\SHARE` or `net use * \\SERVER\SHARE`).
- You could skip the `/I` switch if you're sure there won't be any connections to the share using different character case.
- The two `@` characters prevent the commands from echoing on the console. An alternative is to begin the batch file with `@ECHO OFF'`.
- If you're running this directly on the command line instead of from a batch file, replace the the two `%%D` with `%D`.

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you. Works a treat.

Comment: Just a thought, it maybe easier to change `SET "SHARE=\\servershare\file\sharename\shared"` to be `SET "SHARE=\\servershare\shared"` as your desktop admins would have to type out a long share name.  Newer OS versions do indeed support "deep path" mapping, it maybe advisable to tidy it up a bit...  Your milage may vary..  :)

Comment: Isn't the drive letter in `%%E`? Or alt least for me it is. I mounted a network drive `//my/webdav/share` as `Z:`. I get `//my/webdav/share` for `@echo %%D` and `Z` for `@echo %%E`.